# fetch apiを使って自作のWebサーバーにPOSTリクエストを送ると時間がかかる

Tags: javascript, python, python3

Pythonのhttp.serverで下のようにサーバーを実装し、そのサーバーにブラウザからfetch APIを使ってPOSTしようとしているのですがブラウザが`応答を待っています`という状態のままになってしまいます。
なぜでしょうか?

ブラウザの開発ツールでネットワークの状況を見てみるとhtmlとjavascriptのファイルはGETできているようなのですがPOSTにとても時間がかかっているようです

python server.py:

```
import http.server

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    def do_POST(self):
        # Now this method just print path and content-type.
        print("POSTED")
        content_type = self.headers["Content-Type"]
        print(content_type)
        print(self.path)
        if "multipart/form-data" in content_type:
            raw_data = self.rfile.read()
        self.send_response(200, self.responses[200][0])
        self.send_header("access-control-allow-origin", "*")
        self.end_headers()
        # WIP: do something...

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path[0] == "/":
            self.path = self.path[1:]
        try:
            with open(self.path, "rb") as f:
                file_data = f.read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.send_response(404, self.responses[404][0])
            self.end_headers()
            return
        print(file_data)
        content_length = len(file_data)
        self.send_response(200, self.responses[200][0])
        self.send_header("content-length", content_length)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(file_data)

    def parse_post():
        # WIP
        pass

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(("", 6788), MyHandler)
print("Address:", "", "Port:", 6788)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

js code:

```
let myheaders = new Headers();
myheaders.append("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Hello", "World");
fetch("http://localhost:6788/nk", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    body: formdata,
    header: myheaders
}).then((response)=> response.text()).then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

`mode: "cors"` の場合、ブラウザー側は`CORS-preflight request`を送信するため、サーバー側は`POST`、`GET`リクエストの他に`OPTIONS`リクエストを処理する必要があります。